# Discord.js - Change Role of a given Discord ID

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to change someone's role based his discord ID
I looked around for solutions, but all of them rely on the user messaging the bot (the message event) to retrieve a member object

The thing is, I wanna do it differently, and the only piece of information i have is the discord ID

Code I tried:

```
let User = await client.users.fetch(discord_id),
dm_channel = await User.createDM();
dm_channel.send(msg);
```

I thought I could get to 'message' through a dm, but I guess not..

**Any ideas?**

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. I think you're asking how to change someone's roles without listening to the `message` event of `Client`?

Comment: yea, that's right

Comment: Do you wanna do that when the bot starts or when other events are fired? Such as, when someone joins your guild.

Comment: I wanna call the function from another script

Answer (score 0):

Export your `Client` object; then do `Client.guilds.cache.get("guild id").members.cache.get("user ID").roles.cache.map(x =>` ${x.name}`).join("\n")`

You don't need to export it if you're usin' it in the same index.js file

- To export it, I suggest you read up on how to make a command handler here: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/

You need a GUILD ID since roles only exist in guilds, not in DMs.

Comment: That's great. I retrieved the member object. However when I use member.addRole(role),
where 'member' & 'role' is what i retrieved from your code , it says addRole isn't a function?

Could it have been renamed to something else? Because I can't find it in the original documentation

Comment: nevrmind, I used member.roles.add instead. thx for the help!

Comment: `member.addRole()` was a function on v11; on v12, you need to use `member.roles.add()` as you have done so. Well done!